# How can I add height and width attributes to an image in a menu?

Tags: overrides, images, jhtml

Google is complaining that there is no height and width set on the HTML properties of some images in a menu.  It's worrying about cumulative layout shift.

The sizing is all done in CSS, but I want to add the height/width attributes.  I've created a `mod_menu` override but that doesn't help because I can't even see an `<img` tag.

I see these files

1. default.php
2. default_component.php
3. default_heading.php
4. default_separator.php
5. default_url.php

I think it's being called with this code.  I see this code in `default_component.php` and `default_url.php`.  I've tried changing it in both files.

```
if ($item->menu_image)
{
    if ($item->menu_image_css)
    {
        $image_attributes['class'] = $item->menu_image_css;
        $linktype = JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title, $image_attributes);
    }
    else
    {
        $linktype = JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title);
    }

    if ($item->params->get('menu_text', 1))
    {
        $linktype .= '<span class="image-title">' . $item->title . '</span>';
    }
}
```

I suspect it's specifically this part:

```
JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title, $image_attributes);
```

I saw this part was adding a class

```
$image_attributes['class'] = $item->menu_image_css;
```

So I tried adding

```
$image_attributes['height'] = '308';
$image_attributes['width'] = '308';
```

But that didn't appear to do it.  I then tried:

```
    $linktype = JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title, $image_attributes, ['width' => '308'], ['height' => '308']);
```

but still no joy

How could I add the height and width to these images?

Here is my full edited code

```
if ($item->menu_image)
{
    if ($item->menu_image_css)
    {
        $image_attributes['class'] = $item->menu_image_css;
//        $image_attributes['height'] = '308';
//        $image_attributes['width'] = '308';
        $linktype = JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title, $image_attributes, ['width' => '308'], ['height' => '308']);
    }
    else
    {
        $linktype = JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title);
    }

    if ($item->params->get('menu_text', 1))
    {
        $linktype .= '<span class="image-title">' . $item->title . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attributes are added only when image class is set. If you want dimensions on all images, move the code outside of `$item->menu_image_css` check:

```
if ($item->menu_image)
{
    $image_attributes['height'] = '308';
    $image_attributes['width'] = '308';

    if ($item->menu_image_css)
    {
        $image_attributes['class'] = $item->menu_image_css;
    }

    $linktype = JHtml::_('image', $item->menu_image, $item->title, $image_attributes);

    if ($item->params->get('menu_text', 1))
    {
        $linktype .= '<span class="image-title">' . $item->title . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ha!  What an idiot.  Good man

Comment: Weirdly this doesn't work.  It shows the same old as it used to.

Comment: Have you checked if the override works at all?

Comment: Yep, I echo'd something and I see it selectable in the module too